# ghc 7.6.3 not generating _stub.c and _stub.o

Tags: c++, c, haskell

I'm learning how to make C++ call haskell code from a library, I was following instructions from FFI complete examples http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/FFI_complete_examples

however, after

```
ghc -v Foo.hs
```

only `Foo_stub.h` and `Foo.o` are created, there's no `Foo_stub.c` or `Foo_stub.o`. According to [Calling Haskell from C](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Calling_Haskell_from_C), ghc > 7.2 doesn't generate `_stub.o` anymore.

In this case do I still need a `stub.o` to link an executable **using g++**?

At the moment after

```
g++ -o test Foo.o test.o `cat link_options`
```

I get lots of undefined symbols errors for `hs_init` and the like. Is it because `_stub.o` is not present or something else missing?

I can link them correctly using ghc:

```
ghc -no-hs-main -o test test.o Foo.o -lstdc++
```

(after reading this question:[Building a dynamic library with haskell and using it from C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8690049/building-a-dynamic-library-with-haskell-and-using-it-from-c?rq=1))

but I wonder is it still possible to link using g++?

Comment: Any tip on how to make `C` and `Haskell` get along? I have `ghc 8.4.3` in NixOS. The problem is the same: no Foo_stub.c.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking at an out-of-date example (it's using ghc 6.12.3).  This example works for 7.6.3:

http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/GHC/Using_the_FFI

Comment: I've seen that one but it mentioned nothing about how to link using g++, please let me know if i missed something.

Comment: Quoting GNU.org: When referring to C++ compilation, it is usual to call the compiler “G++”. Since there is only one compiler, it is also accurate to call it “GCC” no matter what the language context; however, the term “G++” is more useful when the emphasis is on compiling C++ programs.  http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.3.6/gcc/G_002b_002b-and-GCC.html

Comment: thanks for the comment...but how does it answer my question? Without stub.o, how do I link the target using g++/gcc, as can be done when they are compiled with ghc 6?